# Authenticated encryption with Signatures

Tags: encryption, signature, mac, authenticated-encryption

I've given a CPA secure private key encryption scheme (wich gets to a CCA secure scheme or better to an authenticated encryption scheme, when i combine it with a given MAC) and a unforgeable public key signature scheme. I want to combine both to get an authenticated encryption scheme.

My approach was to first sign the message and then encrypt(+MAC) the message with the signature. I think this should work.

But is there any possibility to combine the CPA secure private key encryption scheme with the public key signature scheme and get an authenticated encryption scheme, without using the MAC to ensure authenticity and integrity?

Mac AND Signatures seems like doing the same thing twice since encryption+mac leads to an authenticated encryption scheme. But i have to use Signatures in my scheme.

Comment: As this was just released a few days ago, you may want to take a look at the [iMessage attack, which works exactly because the difference between MAC and signatures](http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2016/03/attack-of-week-apple-imessage.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [​ ​ nonce || counter ​ ​ version of CTR mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29)

satisfies the first two of the following conditions.

If

the symmetric encryption scheme is such that different ciphertexts

with the same nonce will decrypt to different plaintexts

and
the symmetric encryption scheme is secure against a *single* chosen ciphertext

whose nonce was *not* used for any of the challenge ciphertexts

and
the signature scheme is [strongly](https://books.google.com/books?id=B-ARBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA352&dq=%22digital+signature%22+%22strong+unforgeability%22) unforgeable

and
the lengths of encodings of [message,signature] pairs don't reveal

any more about the messages than the lengths of the messages

then sign-then-encrypt will work for a single pair of users, but *won't* work with

signature verification keys from parties that aren't supposed to know the plaintexts.

I *suspect* that should generalize to arbitrary stream ciphers.

Comment: Thanks, this was very hepful! 
Is there any problem with using Mac's and Signatures at the same time?

Comment: If the MAC gets signed then you lose _strong_ unforgeability with respect to verifiers that don't know the MAC key. ​ Otherwise, no. ​ ​ ​ ​